# Determine the equation of a hyperbola with foci at $(3,7)$ and $(3,−1)$ and with eccentricity $e=2$.

Tags: conic-sections

Determine the equation of a hyperbola with foci at $(3,7)$ and $(3,−1)$ and with eccentricity $e=2$.

If someone could check my answer that would be great.

By looking at the foci it is easy to deduce that the equation of the hyperbola will be of the form $$\frac{x^2}{b^2}-\frac{y^2}{a^2}=1~~(a>b)$$

We also know that the center will be at $(3,3)$ and so $c=4$ also for a hyperbola $e=\frac{c}{a}=\frac{4}{a}=2 \iff a=2 \implies a^2=4~$  and also $b^2=a^2+c^2 \iff b^2=20$ thus we have the equation as $$\frac{x^2}{20}-\frac{y^2}{4}=1$$

Thanks.

If this is wrong please tell me how so.

Comment: The hyperbola you entered is centered at $(0,0)$. But the midpoint of $(3,7)$ and $(3,-1)$ is not $(0,0)$

Comment: So would it be the same with $(x-3)^2$ and $(y-3)^2$ on the numerators??

Comment: Yes, now put in $ a^2, b^2$.

Answer (score 1):

As the foci lies in $x=3$ which is the  major axis

The midpoint of the foci is centre $(3,3)$

Now the coordinate of the foci $(\alpha,ae\pm\beta)$  where $2a=$ major axis, $(\alpha,\beta)$ is the center and $e=$eccentricity

Finally $b^2=a^2(e^2-1)$ where $2b=$minor axis

Hope this should be sufficient